# Fully connect network with softmax for CIFAR100

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm trying to build a fully connected layer using the CIFAR 100 dataset with softmax and print the accuracy,the learning curve and some of end results – the pictures and their true label and predicted label. 
 I have this following code for the mnist dataset,the problem I'm facing is to how apply the same thing for my data set,I'll try to explain my problem down below:

```
      #initialization
    X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 1])
    w=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
    b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    #model
    Y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(X,[-1, 784]), w)+b)
    #place holder for correct answer
     Y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
    #loss function
     cross_entropy= -tf.reduce_sum(Y_ * tf.log(Y))
     # % of correct answers found in batch
    is_correct=tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1), tf.argmax(Y_,1))
    accurancy= tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(is_correct,tf.float32))
    #training step
    optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003)
    train_step=optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

    sess=tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(10000):
    #load batch of images and correct answer
       batch_x, batch_Y=mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_data={X: batch_x, Y_:batch_y}
     #train
     sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=train_data)

    a,c=sess.run([accurancy, cross_entropy], feed=train_data)

   test_data={X:mnist.test.images, Y_:mnist.test.lables}
   a,c=sess.run([accurancy, cross_entropy], feed=test_data)
```

I have downloaded CIFAR-100 dataset. The CIFAR-100 dataset consists of 60000 32x32 color images. It has 100 classes containing 600 images each. There are 500 training images and 100 testing images per class. The 100 classes in the CIFAR-100 are grouped into 20 superclasses. Each image comes with a "fine" label (the class to which it belongs) and a "coarse" label (the superclass to which it belongs).

I only used 2 super classes “aquatic mammals” and “flowers” each with 5 subcategories

here is some of the code:

```
def unpickle(file):
import pickle
with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
    dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
return dict

# loading train data
data = unpickle('train')
train_data, label_train_data = filter_train(data, 5000)
label_train_data = relabel(label_train_data)

# loading test data
data2 = unpickle('test')
test_data, label_test_data = filter_train(data2, 1000)
label_test_data = relabel(label_test_data)
```

filter_train is just a function I used to fillter the 2 super classes “aquatic mammals” and “flowers”

I know that mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size=100) means it randomly pick 100 data from MNIST dataset

So my Question is how can I exchange the

```
batch_x, batch_Y=mnist.train.next_batch(100)
```

and:

```
  test_data={X:mnist.test.images, Y_:mnist.test.lables}
```

So that I can access the train data and test data of my CIFAR dataset,
I been tring to replace those lines with the
train_data, label_train_data and test_data, label_test_data but it won't seem to work and I can't find any other way to get to those sets.
Any hely would be appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at this guide for [importing your own data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets)?